# Clear a DateBox or attach a DatePicker to a TextBox - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, reset, datebox

Is it possible to clear the value of a DateBox within a handler function?  You can clear the value of a TextBox with just a simple `app.getElementById('id').setValue('');` and you can set the value of a ListBox to a blank value by including `listBox.addItem('')` and then setting the ListBox to that item with `app.getElementById('id').setItemSelected({item # for blank item}, true);` but I have been unable to figure out a way to clear a DateBox.  The goal is to have a simple form that allows users to fill it out and submit the form with a button then have the form auto-reset so the user can fill it out again for a new submission.

Alternatively, if, as I suspect, it is not yet possible to clear a DateBox (feature limitation), then I could simply use a TextBox.  To make things look better (and to help users enter the date in the format the script expects), it would be nice if I could add a DatePicker to the TextBox but other than the old tutorial I found that generates the entire DatePicker function from scratch I haven't found a simple way to attach the new DatePicker GAS Class to a TextBox.

GAS Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-box

Date Picker 2 Tutorial - https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/miscellaneous/date-picker-2

Much simplified sample code that hopefully provides enough information without forcing anyone to read 5 pages of code to get to what I'm trying to highlight.  Note the comments especially in the `submitHandler(e)` function.  This code can be copied into a blank (saved) spreadsheet for testing or you can replace the spreadsheet specific code to just return the app if you're more comfortable doing that.

```
//Opens the active spreadsheet and selects the first sheet.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = sheets[0];

function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test Form');
//Main panel with a 3x2 grid hosting labels and boxes.
var mainVP = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var mainCP = app.createCaptionPanel('Purchase Details');
    var mainG = app.createGrid(3, 2);
      var nameL = app.createLabel('Name');
      var nameT = app.createTextBox().setName('name').setId('name');
      var dateL = app.createLabel('Date');
      var dateD = app.createDateBox().setName('date').setId('date');
      var ownL = app.createLabel('Own/Lease');
      var ownC = app.createListBox().setName('ownLease').setId('ownLease');
//Submit button with auto-reset functionality.
    var subHP = app.createHorizontalPanel().setSize('100%', '40px');
      var subL = app.createLabel('Submitted').setId('subL').setVisible(false);
      var subB = app.createButton('Submit');
//Handler for button.
var subHandler = app.createServerHandler('submitHandler');
subHandler.addCallbackElement(mainVP);
subB.addClickHandler(subHandler);
//Add options to ListBox.
ownC.addItem('').addItem('Own').addItem('Lease');
//Place widgets on Grid.
mainG.setWidget(0, 0, nameL).setWidget(0, 1, nameT)
  .setWidget(1, 0, dateL).setWidget(1, 1, dateD)
  .setWidget(2, 0, ownL).setWidget(2, 1, ownC);
//Aligns the submit Button and Label to the right and adds them to their HPanel.
subHP
  .add(subL).setCellHorizontalAlignment(subL, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
  .add(subB).setCellHorizontalAlignment(subB, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
//Adds stuff to panels so it shows up.
mainCP.add(mainG);
mainVP.add(mainCP);
mainVP.add(subHP);
app.add(mainVP);
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(app);
}

function submitHandler(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//Set variables for each field in the Purchase Details CaptionPanel.
var name = e.parameter.name;
var date = e.parameter.date;
var ownLease = e.parameter.ownLease;
  //I use a sheet.appendRow() method here but for the purposes of this question-
  //we don't actually need the data, just need to clear it.
//Clears data from form to prepare for another submission.
app.getElementById('name').setValue('');
//app.getElementById('date') /* This is the field I need to clear somehow. */
app.getElementById('ownLease').setItemSelected(0, true);
//Displays the word "Submitted" when the Submit Button is clicked.
var label = app.getElementById('subL');
label.setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color', 'blue');
return app;
}
```

In summary:

1. Is there a way to clear the value in a DateBox using a handler function and if so, how?
2. If clearing a DateBox is impossible, how could I add a DatePicker to a TextBox and limit data entry to a specific format (so the TextBox wouldn't take "blahblahblah" as a valid date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a third solution which would be to create a new datepicker widget and add it to your grid to replace the "filled one" ?

here is a test where I do the "replace" in the submit handler but I guess it would be placed in a separate handler called 'submit again' for example...(but that is up to you) :

I changed your submit confirmation to show the date returned by the new datePicker (just to test)

```
//Opens the active spreadsheet and selects the first sheet.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = sheets[0];
var popAttributes = {'padding':'10px','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'fontSize':'10pt','color':'#000099','background':'#ffffee','border-radius':'10px'}
var btnAttributes = {'padding':'3px','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'fontSize':'10pt','border-radius':'6px'}

function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test Form');
//Main panel with a 3x2 grid hosting labels and boxes.
var mainVP = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var mainCP = app.createCaptionPanel('Purchase Details').setStyleAttributes(popAttributes);
    var mainG = app.createGrid(3, 2).setId('grid');
      var nameL = app.createLabel('Name');
      var nameT = app.createTextBox().setName('name').setId('name');
      var dateL = app.createLabel('Date');
      var dateD = app.createDateBox().setName('date').setId('date');
      var ownL = app.createLabel('Own/Lease');
      var ownC = app.createListBox().setName('ownLease').setId('ownLease');
//Submit button with auto-reset functionality.
    var subHP = app.createHorizontalPanel().setSize('100%', '40px');
      var subL = app.createLabel('Submitted').setId('subL').setVisible(false);
      var subB = app.createButton('Submit').setStyleAttributes(btnAttributes);
//Handler for button.
var subHandler = app.createServerHandler('submitHandler');
subHandler.addCallbackElement(mainVP);
subB.addClickHandler(subHandler);
//Add options to ListBox.
ownC.addItem('').addItem('Own').addItem('Lease');
//Place widgets on Grid.
mainG.setWidget(0, 0, nameL).setWidget(0, 1, nameT)
  .setWidget(1, 0, dateL).setWidget(1, 1, dateD)
  .setWidget(2, 0, ownL).setWidget(2, 1, ownC);
//Aligns the submit Button and Label to the right and adds them to their HPanel.
subHP
  .add(subL).setCellHorizontalAlignment(subL, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
  .add(subB).setCellHorizontalAlignment(subB, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
//Adds stuff to panels so it shows up.
mainCP.add(mainG);
mainVP.add(mainCP);
mainVP.add(subHP);
app.add(mainVP);
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(app);
}

function submitHandler(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//Set variables for each field in the Purchase Details CaptionPanel.
var name = e.parameter.name;
var date = e.parameter.date;
var ownLease = e.parameter.ownLease;
  //I use a sheet.appendRow() method here but for the purposes of this question-
  //we don't actually need the data, just need to clear it.
//Clears data from form to prepare for another submission.
app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('date').setName('date'))
app.getElementById('date') /* This is the field I need to clear somehow. */
app.getElementById('ownLease').setItemSelected(0, true);
//Displays the word "Submitted" when the Submit Button is clicked.
var label = app.getElementById('subL');
label.setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color', 'blue').setText(e.parameter.date);// to test the returned date value
return app;
}
```

Comment: That worked.  The key bit of information was how to replace the widget in the grid `app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('date').setName('date'))`.  I didn't realize you could just swap it out like that.  It would still be nice if Google added a .clear() method for DateBox widgets but until then this will suffice.  Thanks.