# Empty a DateBox Value - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have several `DateBox` widgets in a UiApp. With other widgets like `TextBox` I can simply do something like:

`UiApp.getElementById("someTextBox").setText("");`

in order to make the field empty. When I do the same for `DateBox`, the only value it can accept is a `Date` Object, so the closest thing I can come to "empty" is today's date:

`UiApp.getElementById("someDateBox").setValue(new Date());`

I want the `DateBox` to be empty when the UiInstance returns. Is there any way to accomplish this? Do I need to recreate the widget in order to have it be "empty"?

**Edit**: A solution, until a better method is implemented in the `DateBox` class, is to re-create the widget entirely, and replace wherever is was located in the UiApp before. See [Serge's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19055424/1986871) in a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just encountered one of the many flaws in that datebox. You will have to replace it. Beware of other problems. For example I filled an issue in the gas issues page about this: if a user ever selects a date and later clears the date box contents, your doGet will recieve the datebox previous non-empty value. Since you cant possibly detect an empty datebox from code and there is no visual indication to the user that they must fill the date, it was for me a showstopper so I moved to htmlServices and my own date box.

Comment: Darn... I have no problem re-creating the DateBox to simulate an empty value - and fortunately my boss will be the only person using this application, so I don't really need to worry about inconsistencies in empty values. Thanks for confirming my suspicions...

Comment: I must note that the problem I complained about (cant get a cleared datebox) was fixed early this year: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2137

Comment: @Chris-There are validators that work with date box, you can easily use them with client handlers to prevent the empty value or even invalid value cases.  There are a few examples on SO,.